# customized loss, function of both residuals and true values

Tags: python, regression, xgboost, loss-function

I am trying to solve a regression problem where I have to predict for how long a machine will be out of order given its status when it breaks. The goal is to fix **first** machines that are predicted to be out of order for more than 30 days.

I guess that this problem could benefit from a customized loss function
In particular, the points to take into account when writing this customized loss function are:

- We can be "**relaxed**" in predicting machines for which the real broken period is <30 days as machines that will stay out of order for >= 30 days
- It is **NOT OK** to predict machines for which the real broken period is >=30 days as machiens that will stay out of order fr < 30 days

To address the 2 points above I thought it could be a starting point to

- For y < 30 penalize more over estimations
- For y >=30 penalize more underestimations

The code could be something like this:

```
def custom_differentiate_long_short_objective(preds, dtrain):
    labels = dtrain.get_label()
    # create a dataframe with predictions and labels (easier to work)
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({"predictions": preds, "labels": labels})

    # differenciate between machines broken for > 30 days or less
    dataframe_short = dataframe[dataframe["labels"] < 30]
    dataframe_long = dataframe[dataframe["labels"] >= 30]

    # for machines broken for >= 30 custom asymmetric MSE that gives 10 times more penalty when the true targets are more than predictions (underestimation) as compared to when true targets are less (overestimation)
    residual_long = (dataframe_long["labels"] - 
    dataframe_long["predictions"]).astype("float")


    grad_long = residual_long.copy()
    grad_long[residual_long > 0] = -2 * 10.0 * grad_long[residual_long > 0]
    grad_long[residual_long <= 0] = -2 * grad_long[residual_long <= 0]
    hess_long = residual_long.copy()
    hess_long[residual_long > 0] = 2 * 10.0
    hess_long[residual_long <= 0] = 2.0

    # machines broken for < 30 days custom asymmetric MSE that gives 10 times more penalty when the true targets are less than predictions (overestimation) as compared to when true targets are more (underestimation)
    residual_short = (dataframe_short["labels"] - dataframe_short["predictions"]).astype("float")
    grad_short = residual_short.copy()
    grad_short[residual_short < 0] = -2 * 10.0 * grad_short[residual_short < 0]
    grad_short[residual_short >= 0] = -2 * grad_short[residual_short >= 0]
    hess_short = residual_short.copy()
    hess_short[residual_short < 0] = 2 * 10.0
    hess_short[residual_short >= 0] = 2.0

    grad = pandas.concat([grad_short, grad_long]).values
    hess = pandas.concat([hess_short, hess_long]).values

return grad, hess
```

What I would like to add now is to make the loss is proportional to the distance from the threshold.... for y very close to 30 the loss should be higher...
I am stuck here...any advice?
Does it make sense?

Comment: Based on my personal engineering experience with nuclear and industrial equipment, I don't think you have sufficient information in the model to make a useful estimation of equipment down time. That is, without information on why the equipment is out of service there cannot be a reasonable estimate of repair time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but not pertinent with my question..